# I cannot get the Klaxon dependency in Intellij to register

Tags: gradle, kotlin, klaxon

I for the life of me cannot seem to get the Klaxon dependency to work in Intellij. Other dependencies I have added (like gson) have worked fine. I have tried refreshing Gradle, tried a different version, etc. Nothing seems to be working so I can use the library. I could be missing something obvious (new to Gradle and Kotlin). Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Gradle Script:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.11'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8",
            "com.beust:klaxon:5.0.5"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Import Won't Register

https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon

[image]

Comment: Did you try to refresh the `Refresh All Gradle Projects` action in IntelliJ / Android Studio?

Comment: You may try to add yet another dedicated `compile` for the second dependency instead of the `,` on the previous line

Comment: Hi Eugene, I tried the refresh all, but no luck yesterday. Also tried to use a second compile. Still no luck. It is very odd

Comment: It was not having jcenter() as @rj2700 pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So where are you getting this download from? Is it from below?

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/klaxon/5.0.5

If so, you need to add the jcenter() repo, like so:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

I saw it because in the above link, it says that the repo is from Jcenter. I also tried searching the mavenCentral repo and couldn't find the klaxon directory.

http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/beust/

If this isn't an issue, try refreshing your dependencies through Gradle like so:

```
(from proj dir) $ gradle clean
(from proj dir) $ gradle --refresh-dependencies
```

Comment: I had the same problem as you OP, and I added the jcenter repository, and everything works fine now.

Comment: Thanks, @rj2700 and Ctorres that was it. I figured I was missing something stupid. I did not catch the jcenter bit.